# UITableView blinks while moving an iPhone

Tags: ios, uiview

The visualisation of the problem is under link below as a video:

Link:: [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhdaslfv5qsdpt7/bug.mov?dl=0)

`UICollectionView` blinks because (I think) it is re-rendered only when **Portrait Orientation Lock** is **Off**, otherwise blinking disappear.

Comment: make sure you are not reloading the table view in infinite loop.

Comment: kindly add your code, it will be more helpful

Answer (score -1):

Your screen recording indicates you are using `UITableView`.

So for sure you call `reloadData()` somewhere on your table. Take into consideration methods related to changing orientation... and let me know about results.